# Moving Google Analytics Accounts Within GA

Tags: google-analytics

On my google analytics page I have a bunch of "accounts" in my overview that I want to move under 1 "account" as "profiles"

How can this be accomplished without losing past data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, see: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=3016c4995db25139&hl=en